# Bootstrap - Tokenfield, store values as an array not a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, token

I am using https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield, and noticed that the values are stored as a string, not an array.  Is there a way to store the values as an array instead of a string?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value='A,B,C' />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ds2xp4w1/1/

I also noticed that the value attribute does not seem update.

Comment: `split(',')` could also work here

Comment: I am looking to see if there is an option to change it when the library? or a way to change it on submit?

Comment: In your fiddle it is already storing values in string. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/7s5xkLon/1/

Comment: @Kishan, that is correct, I need it stored as an array per my post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two way are there

1.Store `,` separate string the convert to array while in dom using `split(',')`

```js
console.log($('#tokenfield').val().trim().split(','))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value='A,B,C' />
```

2.`JSON.stringify()` format .convert the string to array

```js
$('#tokenfield').val(JSON.stringify(['A','B','C']))

//after retrive

console.log(JSON.parse($('#tokenfield').val()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value='' />
```

Comment: If I do that when the value changes, the tokens do not work, as it needs to be a string for the token to appear correctly. However, I need it to be an array for my params to work on form submit. Ideas?

Comment: yes .  im not familier with that github  lib.Please provide some working fiddle?

Comment: ,did you review the fiddle I posted?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8cmob4h6/ .i added click function you need to call that function on submit

Comment: Yes, I see what your are doing, but the value needs to update and still maintain the proper tags in the UI. Your example shows how to convert a string to an array, but does not solve the main issue, of being able to store the value to submit in a param as array, and still maintain the proper UI. thank you for helping

Comment: i think you need re-update the source array from input value after form submit right?  or tell *but the value needs to update* `where?` and `what is main issue?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190099/discussion-between-user2012677-and-prasanth).